# Raising a "null" exception in Python

Tags: python

I am trying to write a function that does error checking in the following way.

```
def check_var_type(var, var_name, type):
    t = type(var)
    if t is type or t is list:
        return None
    else:
        return TypeError(
            f"Invalid {var_name} type '{t.__module__}.{t.__name__}', "
            f"'{float.__module__}.{float.__name__}' or "
            f"'{list.__module__}.{list.__name__}' expected.")


my_var = 1
raise check(my_var, 'my_var', float)
```

My expectation of Python's `raise` command was that if I pass `None` to it, it would simply ignore it and raise no exception. The response, however, was:

```
TypeError: exceptions must derive from BaseException
```

I then had a look at Python's [built-in exception types](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html) to see if something like `Nonthing`, `NoError`, etc. exists. No luck though.

I can, of course raise the exception in the `check_var_type` function, but I don't want to, since this would add an extra line to the stack trace.

So, my (perhaps silly) question is: How can I use `raise` to not raise an exception? :-)

Thanks

Comment: Is there a reason you don't just raise the `TypeError` instead of returning it?

Comment: I don't think you could use `raise` for anything else that raising exceptions. IMHO, adding a line to back trace is not so disturbing. Finally, you could get the result of your function and raise it if it is not None.

Comment: @JETM: Yes, as I explained, I don't want the stack trace to point into the check_var_type function, but rather to the line where I call raise.

Comment: Then catch it at the call and raise a new one. There's pretty much only one thing you should be doing with exceptions: raising them. Why do you even care how many lines the backtrace has?

Comment: That's mostly a non-issue. The stack trace will say `foo_function → check_var_type`, so it's pretty easy to spot that, yes, the error was raised in the latter, but the former initiated that check, so it's easy to spot where the actual problem is located.

Comment: @Tryph: It can still kind of be raising an exception, perhaps of type "NoException", but preferably just "None". raise could just interpret it it by ignoring it if it is None. Adding a line to the stack trace seems to be my fate. Returning the exception and then raising it would add an if statement, which I don't want to do either. I know... I am picky.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to raise an exception, don't call `raise` (whose sole job IS to raise an exception).

Perhaps what you really want is to call `raise` from *inside* `check_var_type` when you actually do want to raise an exception, and just use `return` when you don't.

An alternative might be to leave `check_var_type` as is, but wrap the call to it in an `if` that one raises the exception returned when an exception is returned.

Comment: Thanks Scott. I do believe that it would be a helpful addition to the language if one could use raise None.

Comment: Why would you raise None? If by that you mean raise nothing then don't raise if you want generic exception then use raise Exception

Comment: It is analogous to a for loop such as "for i in range(a, b):", which would do nothing if a and b are equal.

Comment: @johzi The line `for ...` will still do something, only the *following indented block* won't. Same with `raise` and `return` and similar, those lines will always do something.

Comment: True, @deceze, but there would effectively be nothing happening as a consequence.

Comment: @johzi It would be possible for Python to have a special rule that says "if the program tries to raise `None` (or some other special value) then the `raise` command is ignored", but it would odd and confusing and essentially redundant because it's incorporating the behaviour of an `if` statement into a `raise`.

Comment: @johzi It would arguably be very hard to follow a piece of code if you couldn't be sure whether a line that says `raise` will or won't `raise`. There's no discernible difference between `raise foo()` and `raise bar()`, where `foo` is an exception type and will cause a raise, and `bar` being a function which may or may not return `None` and may or may not cause an exception to be raised and the following code to be executed or not.

Comment: @khelwood That is exactly what I thought could be done to incorporate it into the language, if not None then perhaps NoError. The latter would be more explicit and perfectly clear. It would provide the freedom to implement the use case I posted.

Comment: It would be _less_ explicit and less clear, because it would mean that `raise` contained an _implicit_ `if` statement. It would mean `raise` is only _sometimes-raise_. If I see a `raise` statement in the code, I could only tell that it _might_ raise, or it might be ignored.

Comment: @khelwood You make a strong point. My perspective is perhaps a bit different. But I like yours.